# What would an observer in the most distant galaxy see?

Tags: cosmology

Perhaps this has been asked before and perhaps it's rather trivial, but what would an observer on the most distant astronomical object see? Would they see only the CMB in one direction and us in the other direction, or would they see essentially the same thing as us, i.e. a universe of diameter $8.8\times 10^{26}$ m which looks uniform in every direction? If it's the later case, doesn't this imply that the cosmos has infinite mass?

Comment: People don't really use meters to describe cosmic distances.  Millions or billions of light years are better as they also tell you the timescale involved, not just the distance.

Comment: I was just using wikipedia as my guide, but I take your point.

Comment: Homogeneous and isotropic Friedmann universes can have either infinite or finite volume and mass, depending on whether they have negative, zero, or positive spatial curvature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting this question as "what lies beyond the observable universe?", asked in different words. The answer to that is "we don't know", because things that are beyond the observable universe are by definition not observable, so there could be invisible pink unicorns out there which we cannot prove doesn't exist. Any possible answer is therefore speculation.

Still, the natural answer would be "more of the same". That I think is the assumption of most astronomers, albeit knowing full well that it is an unknowable question. See e.g. this [popular-level article](https://dailygalaxy.com/2019/02/beyond-the-observable-universe-more-of-the-same-or-sea-monsters-and-dragons-weekend-feature/).

Another way of interpreting the question is whether an observer in a very far away galaxy will see things differently from us. This is asking about [homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneity_(physics)) - is the universe the same at every point? This is a fundamental assumption in deriving the [Friedmann-Robertson-Lemaitre-Walker metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric), which in turn underpins modern cosmology. So the answer is we expect the observer to see the same things as us. Caveat: homogeneity is an assumption. We have good reason to believe the universe is not very inhomogeneous, but we cannot prove it is homogeneous from some more fundamental theory. Neither can we fly a probe to Andromeda and test homogeneity that way. If the universe isn't homogeneous then the FRLW metric would have to be modified, but that doesn't rewrite cosmology entirely, since the more basic theory - general relativity - remains valid.